# how to hide loading image after load chart in d3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

```html
 $(document).on('click', '.tbtn', function(e) {
    $('#loading-image').show();
    if(error){
    $('loading-image').hide();
   else{
    val = $('.barbtn input:checked').val();  
    draw_summary($.parseJSON(data['summary']),val);
    draw_barchart($.parseJSON(data['barchart']),val);
    draw_scatter($.parseJSON(data['table']),val);
    $('#loading-image').show();
  }
});
```

Here i have drawing charts using d3...charts are coming correctly but i need to set loading image when i onclick the button...this code is not working

how to set loading image when onclick the button?

Comment: Can you share HTML code also?

Comment: my code have 1000 lines

Comment: you need that button code alone right?

Comment: Where is the `error` variable being defined?

Comment: i forgot to remove error variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
$(document).on('click', '.tbtn', function(e) {
  $('#loading-image').show();
  $.ajax({
    success:function(result){
      val = $('.barbtn input:checked').val();  
      draw_summary($.parseJSON(data['summary']),val);
      draw_barchart($.parseJSON(data['barchart']),val);
      draw_scatter($.parseJSON(data['table']),val);
      $('#loading-image').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set CSS for it. Otherwise you are following right path. Please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tbtn-hide', function(e) {
 $('#loading-image').hide(); //hide loader
});
$(document).on('click', '.tbtn-show', function(e) {
    $('#loading-image').show(); //show loader
});
```

```css
#loading-image
    {
        background: white url("http://smallenvelop.com/demo/simple-pre-loader/images/loader-64x/Preloader_1.gif") no-repeat scroll center center;;
        height: 80%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 10;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="tbtn-hide">Hide</button>
<button class="tbtn-show">show</button>
<div id="loading-image" style="display:none">
</div>
```

Comment: i have to stop loading image after loading charts

Comment: In your code you forgot to add `#` at the time of hiding it. it should be `$('#loading-image').hide();` instead of `$('loading-image').hide();`

Comment: ya i have added # ...but it does not hide

Comment: Can you add your code in jsfiddle? So that I can help you in proper way.

Comment: its very difficult becs...my code have above 1000 lines and d3 codes are present different functions in different files

Comment: No. Sorry for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117987/discussion-between-trimantra-software-solution-and-sai-rajesh).